# How to get inserted row id in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.4

We created a school table with id = 56.

then We created a activity table with id = 1.

Now How to save school_id = 56 in activity table.

I have a problem. How do I get insert id from schools table?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $activity = new Activity();
        $activity->cluster_id = $request->cluster_id;
        $activity->group_id = $request->group_id;
        $activity->school_id = School::id;
        $activity->save();

        return response()->json(['data' => $request->all(), 'id' => $activity->school->id]);
    }
}
```

Database

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('school_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('cluster_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
        $table->foreign('cluster_id')->references('id')->on('clusters');
        $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups');
    });
}
```

Model

```
class Activity extends Model
{
    public function school()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SchoolsList::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You already insert data in table and get  school_id = 56 as response and on that base you insert next data in table activity  ?

Comment: no, do not insert next data in table activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your School Model save method looks like this :

```
 $school = new School;
 $school->title = 'Baghoon High School';
 $school->location= 'Bangladesh';
 $school->save();
```

then you want to run this code

```
if($request->ajax()) {
    $activity = new Activity();
    $activity->school_id = $school->id;
    $activity->save();
    return response()->json(['data' => $request->all(), 'id' => $school->id]);
}
```